# npm opencv installation fail in mac?

Tags: node.js, opencv, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I am trying to install opencv for vehicle detection in realtime. While installing opencv in terminal it always fail to install

Parameshs-MacBook-Air:pyrky_nodejs parameshv$ npm install opencv --save

> opencv@6.0.0 install /Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/opencv
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://node-opencv.s3.amazonaws.com/opencv/v6.0.0/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for opencv@6.0.0 and node@10.8.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://node-opencv.s3.amazonaws.com/opencv/v6.0.0/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for opencv@6.0.0 and node@10.8.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/init.o
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/init.o
sed: ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/opencv/src/init.o.d.raw: No such file or directory
make: *** [Release/obj.target/opencv/src/init.o] Error 1
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/Matrix.o
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:238:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.8.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/opencv/build/opencv/v6.0.0/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/opencv.node" "--module_name=opencv" "--module_path=/Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/opencv/build/opencv/v6.0.0/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/opencv
gyp ERR! node -v v10.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.8.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/opencv/build/opencv/v6.0.0/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/opencv.node --module_name=opencv --module_path=/Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/opencv/build/opencv/v6.0.0/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (/Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:249:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.8.0/bin/node" "/Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/opencv
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.8.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.8.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/opencv/build/opencv/v6.0.0/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/opencv.node --module_name=opencv --module_path=/Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/opencv/build/opencv/v6.0.0/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64' (1)
npm WARN opencv@6.0.0 had bundled packages that do not match the required version(s). They have been replaced with non-bundled versions.
npm WARN pyrky@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! opencv@6.0.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the opencv@6.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/parameshv/.npm/_logs/2018-09-04T05_34_09_181Z-debug.log
Parameshs-MacBook-Air:pyrky_nodejs parameshv$
Parameshs-MacBook-Air:pyrky_nodejs parameshv$
Parameshs-MacBook-Air:pyrky_nodejs parameshv$ ../src/Matrix.cc:2:10: fatal error: 'Matrix.h' file not found

## include "Matrix.h"

```
     ^~~~~~~~~~
```

1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/opencv/src/Matrix.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:238:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.8.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/opencv/build/opencv/v6.0.0/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/opencv.node" "--module_name=opencv" "--module_path=/Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/opencv/build/opencv/v6.0.0/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/parameshv/pyrky_nodejs/node_modules/opencv
gyp ERR! node -v v10.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
gyp ERR! not ok

Tried to fix this installing

brew tap brewsci/science

brew install pkg-config opencv@2

brew link opencv@2 --force

npm install opencv --save

How to install opencv npm in mac os? Any help much appreciates pls....